# HttpRequest.open is throwing a _uri error about strings?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I end up with a function which was working until recently it seems.  I have the following code:

```
String url = "https://this.is.a.test.com/hello?varA=false";
var request = new HttpRequest();
request.open("GET", url);
...
```

The following error throws when attempting to call open, so i ensured that the URL Link is correct, but referencing it through a browser.  It also works.

> type '_Uri' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'url' where
>
> _Uri is from dart:core
>
> String is from dart:core

At first, I thought the link was wrong until I had tested it.  When i looked at what open did it referenced: *html_dartium.dart* and i noticed the following definition, which is what my intellisense allowed me to jump to:

```
@DomName('XMLHttpRequest.open')
@DocsEditable()
void open(String method, String url, {bool async, String user, String password}) {
  if (async == null && user == null && password == null) {
    _blink.BlinkXMLHttpRequest.instance.open_Callback_2_(this, method, url);
  } else {
    _blink.BlinkXMLHttpRequest.instance.open_Callback_5_(this, method, url, async, user, password);
  }
}
```

I am not sure what is going on here with this package.  I am also unsure where this was pulled from, as i am thinking something may have been broke,through another source.  Right now I am using:

```
browser: ^0.10.0
polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.16
web_components: ^0.12.0
polymer_elements: ^1.0.0-rc.8
uuid: ^0.5.1
http: 0.11.3+7
```

any nothing is quite jumping out at me.

As of right now, this is an error in Dartium only, so I am guessing it is just an issue with Checked mode being permanently on.  I tried the same in Chrome and it referenced and downloaded the file just fine.

Has anyone else encountered this, and have a fix so that it will continue?

Comment: Try deleting the `.pub` directory in your project directory.

Comment: Please show import statements in your code it is possible to see which library `HttpRequest`comes from. I suspect you are passing `open()` a String but it takes a `Uri`.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus thats what I thought.  As you can see in my question, the file it looks like it was referencing was *html_dartium.dart* and the code above was the signature, showing that it was a `String url`

Comment: actually it seams you are passing an `Uri` instead of a `String` not the contrary. You should check your code, try inspecting the actual value of the `url` variable you are passing.